# GE Front Load washer doesn't spin

Tags: washing-machine

Today my 7 years old GE Front Load washer (MODE WCVH6800J1WW) doesn't work.

1. It can fill water successfully, then didn't spin to wash but start to pump water out, then unlock door but time still stay at 50mins.
2. If I switch to "Drain & Spin" mode, the spin works fine and water pump out just like works great for this mode.
3. Even if I use the BlasketClean mode, it will fill water then pump out but not spin at all.

I guess some sensor maybe doesn't work which will cause it think no water or something like that! Write mail to manufacture but no response till now!
[image]

Comment: Found a useful link http://www.appliance-repair-it.com/GE-front-load-washer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use service mode to debug anything wrong with your washer! it will debug item by item till you locate the abnormal function then you can find right solution to fix it.

From the behavior, it mostly like the water pressure component has some problem,which will cause it can not detect water is enough to trigger spin process. for example: water pressure controller abnormal or the water pipe leak water,which will cause water pressure detection fail also.